# define an enum using include

Tags: c++, enums, include

I define an enums using include,since there are different enums which have the same enumeration data and I want to reuse it:

```
#define X(SYM) SYM
#define X_INIT(SYM,VAL) SYM = VAL
/// Destination for scalar memory read instruction
enum SSRC
{

#include "GenericInstructionFields1.h"
#include "ScalarInstructionFields.h"
#include "GenericInstructionFields2.h"

};
enum SDST
{

        #include "GenericInstructionFields1.h"
};

#undef X_INIT
#undef X
};
```

But I can`t compile the code for SDST. The compiler writes redefinition for a fields of SSRC,which comes from "GenericInstructionFields1.h". What is the cause of the problem and how can it be solved?

```
//GenericInstructionFields1.h
/// SGPR0 to SGPR103: Scalar general-purpose registers.
X_INIT(ScalarGPRMin,0),
X(ScalarGPR),
X_INIT(ScalarGPRMax,103),
/// 104 – 105 reserved.
X(Reserved104),
X(Reserved105),
X_INIT(Reserved,2),
/// vcc[31:0].
X_INIT(VccLo, 106),
/// vcc[63:32].
X(VccHi),
```

Comment: @AlokSave It will be silly to put an include guard for the use case he is describing.

Comment: @AlokSave - no - you need read what he has described. He wants to reuse the header in the same translation unit. Putting include guards defeats this purpose.

Comment: @AlokSave Can't you see the same header files included multiple times in the same translation unit? How do you reconcile an include guard with this. And my answer is based on his code. His posted code has an enum inside an enum.

Comment: @AlokSave - I can. What about you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums are not like namespaces.

You will see the same error with the following

```
enum A
{
    P, Q
};

enum B
{
    P, Q
};
```

You can achieve what you want by this

```
struct A
{
    enum { P, Q };
};

struct B
{
    enum { P, Q };
};
```

You can now use A::P, A::Q, B::P & B::Q

Or in your case

```
#define X(SYM) SYM
#define X_INIT(SYM,VAL) SYM = VAL
/// Destination for scalar memory read instruction

struct SSRC
{
    enum
    {

        #include "GenericInstructionFields1.h"
        #include "ScalarInstructionFields.h"
        #include "GenericInstructionFields2.h"

    }

};

struct SDST
{
    enum 
    {
        #include "GenericInstructionFields1.h"
    }
};

#undef X_INIT
#undef X
};
```

You can now use `SSRC::ScalarGPRMax` and `SDST::ScalarGPRMax`

Comment: Note: you would prefer `struct` here, because `class` defaults to `private` accessibility. Note: you should probably name the enum, I've found that using `Type` works well for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can't have enumerations with the same enumerators in the same namespace. This would reproduce your problem:

```
enum X {A,B};
enum Y {A};
```

either use namespaces or prefix your enum values.

Comment: +1 but the latter isn’t hard at all in this case, it’s enough to trivially redefine the two macros for each enum. Incidentally, a third (and the best) alternative is to use C++11 enum classes.

Comment: @Konrad: you're right, I've removed that remark from my answer.